# What do :+ and :or do on Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to do my homework and hacking through some example code I saw this line:

```
   [(:+ (:or VAR)) (token-VAR (string->symbol lexeme))]
```

This is from a lexical analyzer in a calculator;

Now I'm not really sure what either of this does, and I'm not particularly sure what this means exactly, but I'm pretty sure it has what I need to finish my homework. Searching hasn't gotten me any help so all help is great at this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sample code probably imported [`parser-tools`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/parser-tools/index.html) using the `:` prefix (which is the recommended prefix in the parser-tools documentation. If that's the case, then `:+` means "repetition one or more times" and `:or` matches any of the subpatterns (just `VAR` in this case).

Comment: Ok, I looked in the code and it has this:

    '(require parser-tools/yacc
         parser-tools/lex
         (prefix-in : parser-tools/lex-sre))'

Thanks for the reply, but yeah, thins isn't really the problem I'm having then. Thanks!

Comment: He did answer the question you asked though.  ;)  You should probably accept Jacob's answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, This was actually my first post and didn't know about that.  Lemme do that. :)